# I am working on Matlab audio watermarking but it audiowrite is not working

Tags: matlab, audio

I am working on a project on MATLAB in audio watermarking but the audiowrite function is not working well as the wavwrite in previous versions were used and worked well.

```
y = y/max(abs(y));
audiowrite('masked.wav',y,fs);
```

The error that it is showing that the values are not real.

Comment: want to fix this in set watermarking
https://github.com/pondjames007/AudioWatermarking

Comment: Just follow the error. Probably y or fs are complex valued?

Comment: wavwrite took the complex values but audiowrite not